how to do a flutter authentication with microsoft for web
I want to authenticate in a webapp at microsoft using flutter. I started using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth
For my Mobile Platforms it works like a charm, but something is not working in my webapp redirecting flow. It opens the microsoft page and after authentiation, i am getting successfully redirected to my app. But when returning, the code that comes after the login is not getting executed. Here is my code
Future<String?> loginUserWithMicrosoft(User user, String adminID) async {
  final Config config = Config(
    tenant: "common",
    clientId: "xxx",
    scope:
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite offline_access",
    redirectUri: "xxx",
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  );

  try {
    final AadOAuth oauth = AadOAuth(config);
    print("Initiating Login");

    final result = await oauth.login();
    print("Login Result: $result");

    return result.fold(
      (l) {
        print("Login Failed: $l");
        return null;
      },
      (r) {
        print("Login Successful: $r");
        if (r.refreshToken != null) {
          updateUserRefreshToken(adminID, user.userID, r.refreshToken!);
        }
        if (r.accessToken != null) {
          updateUserAccessToken(adminID, user.userID, r.accessToken!);
        }
        return r.accessToken;
      },
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error during login: $e");
    return null;
  }
}

The Code: print("Login Result: $result"); is not getting called anymore. It just prints out everything until the login command. The code after is not executed. Consequently i do also not receive any token. In the Documentation it says something like you need to call login a second time. not sure tho in what way, since code after the first login is discarded..

To make sure, did you already implement for web usage?

yes i did. what i dont understand there it says: "Your application must take care of calling login() again once reloaded to complete the login process within the flutter application - if login was successful, this second call will be fast, and will not cause another redirection." wondering how and where to do this. Since the code after the login statement ist discarded.

So basically for web login you need to call login() twice that executed when first click login then redirect, after redirect you need to call the login again, before you call the second login() you need to assign config.webUseRedirect = false so the second call will not do the redirect, then get the token after that second call. For more example detail see this example.

where am i supposed to do that, without the user having to click login again? somewhere in the mainFile? and dont i need to add an access code into the config then? how do i retreive that?

have you tried to create the login() function in redirectUri page with the same config? (initiate the redirectUri page with login() function to check if the login is successfull or not, so the user doesn't have to click the login button again)

I successfully authenticated the Flutter application and obtained the access token using the aad_oauth package in the web app.
main.dart :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Azure AD Login',
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      home: LoginPage(navigatorKey: navigatorKey), 
    );
  }
}

login_page.dart :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aad_oauth/aad_oauth.dart';
import 'package:aad_oauth/model/config.dart';
import 'home_page.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;
  late final AadOAuth oauth;
  LoginPage({Key? key, required this.navigatorKey}) : super(key: key) {
    final config = Config(
      tenant: "<TenantID>",
      clientId: "<ClientID>",
      scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite offline_access",
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:8000/",
      webUseRedirect: true,
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    );
    oauth = AadOAuth(config);
  }
  Future<String?> loginUserWithMicrosoft() async {
    try {
      final result = await oauth.login();
      return result.fold(
            (l) {
          print("Login Failed: $l");
          return null;
        },
            (r) {
          print("Login Successful: $r");
          return r.accessToken; 
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error during login: $e");
      return null;
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final accessToken = await loginUserWithMicrosoft();
            if (accessToken != null) {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => HomePage(token: accessToken, oauth: oauth), 
                ),
              );
            } else {
              showError("Login failed or access token is null");
            }
          },
          child: Text('Login with Azure AD'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void showError(String message) {
    print(message);
  }
}

home_page.dart :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aad_oauth/aad_oauth.dart';
import 'login_page.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String token;
  final AadOAuth oauth;
  const HomePage({Key? key, required this.token, required this.oauth}) : super(key: key);
  void logout(BuildContext context) async {
    await oauth.logout();
    print("Logged out");
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage(navigatorKey: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>())),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Logged in successfully!\nYour access token: $token'),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => logout(context),
              child: Text('Logout'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

index.html :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flutter AAD OAuth</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.13.1/js/msal-browser.min.js" integrity="sha384-2Vr9MyareT7qv+wLp1zBt78ZWB4aljfCTMUrml3/cxm0W81ahmDOC6uyNmmn0Vrc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="assets/packages/aad_oauth/assets/msalv2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>

I have added the URL below in the AD app's redirect URI as a Web, as shown below.
http://localhost:8000/


Output :
I used port 8000 to run the Flutter application as a web app in Chrome.
flutter run -d chrome --web-port 8000


Browser Output :
I successfully logged in by clicking on the Login with Azure AD button as shown below.

I got the access token, as shown below.


Nice! how do you handle refreshing the access token after initial request?
